# Custom Drupal 7 Field only saves the first character

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fields, drupal-field-api

I'm essentially trying to create my first field type module using the new Drupal 7 Field API.
I've managed to get it to display correctly in the "edit" view.
However, when I try to save some data it only saves the first character.

Here's the module:

```
<?php

function youtubefield_field_info() {
  return array(
    'youtubefield_video' => array(
      'label' => t('Youtube video'),
      'description' => t('This field stores a youtube video ID and displays the video associated with it'),
      'settings' => array(
        'max_length' => 11,
      ),
      'instance_settings' => array(
        'text_processing' => false,
      ),
      'default_widget' => 'youtubefield_video_widget',
      'default_formatter' => 'youtubefield_video_formatter',
    ),
  );
}

function youtubefield_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
    'youtubefield_video_widget' => array(
      'label' => t('Default'),
      'field types' => array('youtubefield_video'),
    ),
  );
}

function youtubefield_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
  $element['#type'] = 'textfield';
  $element['#default_value'] = isset($items[$delta]) ? $items[$delta] : '';
  return $element;
}

function youtubefield_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
  return !$item;
}

function youtubefield_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
    'youtubefield_video_formatter' => array(
      'label' => t('Youtube video'),
      'field types' => array('youtubefield_video'),
    ),
  );
}
```

And here's the installer:

```
<?php

function youtubefield_field_schema($field) {
  return array(
    'columns' => array(
      'value' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 11,
        'not null' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'indexes' => array(),
  );
}
```

EDIT: The problem seems to be related to the widget, as it works fine when it gets the data programmatically.

Comment: @Laxman13, wouldn't it be better to prefix the `field-api` tag with `drupal-`?

Comment: Yes, wasn't thinking, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This widget form worked for me:

```
function youtubefield_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta,\
 $element) {
  $main_widget = array();
  switch ($instance['widget']['type']) {
  case 'youtubefield_video_widget':
    $main_widget = $element + array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['value']) ? $items[$delta]['value'] : NULL,
      );
    break;
  }
  $element['value'] = $main_widget;
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! After some debugging I found that the solution from this answer is the render array returning the `$element` array with `value` as keyvalue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and discoverd hook_field_widget_form() needs to return: "$element['value']"

```
function field_youtube_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {

    $element['value'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['value']) ? $items[$delta]['value'] : NULL,
    );

    return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your widget form to:

```
function youtubefield_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) { 
  switch ($instance['widget']['type']) {  
      case 'youtubefield_video_widget':  
        $element['youtubefield_video'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',  
            '#title' => $element['#title'],  
            '#description' => $element['#description'], 
            '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['youtubefield_video']) ? $items[$delta]['youtubefield_video'] : NULL,  
            '#required' => $element['#required'],  
            '#weight' => isset($element['#weight']) ? $element['#weight'] : 0,  
            '#delta' => $delta,  
        ); 

      break; 
  } 
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you offer an explanation, please? :)